# ssh failed because I can not press [Enter] key

Tags: ssh

I've two machines.

- m1: Solaris Sparc SunOS 5.10
- m2: ArchLinux 3.4.4
- m3: Solaris Sparc SunOS 5.10

When I try to login m2 from m1, I can not press [**Enter**] key, it just display **^M**.

```
m1$ export TERM=vt100
m1$ ssh m2
pkcs11 engine does not exist
The authenticity of host 'm2 (192.168.1.2)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is cf:f2:b7:24:d6:d2:b6:fe:b1:e8:72:6d:2b:cd:55:fe.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes^M
```

my stty is strange

```
m1$ stty -a
... eol = <undef>

m3$ stty -a
... eol = -^?
```

I force the eol become ^M, it can ssh m2 from m1, but will generate a message:

```
pkcs11 engine does not exist
```

If I ssh m2 from m3, it won't show the message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`^M` is ASCII control code for "Carriage Return" whereas ssh is expecting a "Line Feed" or `^J`  If you press Ctrl+J you may be able to log in.

Comment: I'm getting this error suddenly when running the `ssh-keygen` command, and this at least got me over my immediate pecurliar hump.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was just something broken with my current Shell (zsh on Mac). Closing the terminal window and opening it again to run the `ssh` command again fixed the problem and I was able to press Enter again to log in.